# Django-Rest: Need to get all data in batch wise from oracle

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-rest-framework, cx-oracle

I need to create Django rest API- fetching data from Oracle DB, apply pagination, send back to response.
For that, I am taking no_of_rows_per_page and page_no, and fetching all data. I am using fetchall() method. By this method we are getting all data from DB first, then pagination apply and send back as response. By this process, we need to call next page data, we are getting the same process again(Loading all data again from DB). For that our application is taking too much time (Database connected through VPN and Table having millions of records)

For this, I need to fetch data in batch, for that, I used fetchmany(no_of_rows_per_page) method and returning back as response. Since Oracle return each time random rows, getting duplicate/same rows in next page call.

Help needed on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Without seeing the code you are working with it will be more difficult to help you out.  Please see the following for a guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example